# Can I use JDialog for this?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm currently attempting to make a simple work scheduling program. I'm trying to implement a way to add employee's and their info into but I'm a little stuck.

What I wanted to do was have a button that opens up a new window that will let me input their name (string), total hours to work per week (int), and their availability (array, check boxes that will translate to an array). Is it possible to customize a JDialog to do this or is there a better way to go about doing this? I tried reading tutorials on JDialogs but none of it explains how to implement multiple inputs.

I currently have it to where I'm opening up a new JFrame but I've read from multiple sources that I shouldn't do that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: An alternative to using a JDialog would be to layout several components (JCheckBoxes, JButtons) to a JFrame using layout managers.

Comment: `"I tried reading tutorials on JDialogs but none of it explains how to implement multiple inputs."` -- This is no different than adding multiple components such as JTextFields, JRadioButtons, JComboBoxes in a JFrame. Please show us your attempt and clarify just what has you stuck. @Woodrow: that's not an alternative and is not mutually exclusive. Just like in a JFrame you'd place components in JPanels first, and then add the main JPanel to the top level window whether it's a JDialog or JFrame.

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with a JFrame per se. AFAIK, the main difference between a JDialog and a JFrame is that a dialog can be modal. (So if you need a window to be modal, then JFrame is of course wrong since only JDialogs can be modal)

Comment: @immibis: there's more to it than that. The JDialog cannot by itself shut down the JVM when it is closed like a JFrame can. A separate JFrame will create a new icon for the OS's task bar. The JDialog automatically is shown above the parent window and stays there -- so there are several innate behaviors that are very different.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I thought JDialog only let you use JoptionPane inside it. I ended up adding a Panel to the JDialog and setting up like I did before.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried reading tutorials on JDialogs but none of it explains how to implement multiple inputs.

This is no different than adding multiple components such as JTextFields, JRadioButtons, JComboBoxes in a JFrame. For both you'd create a main JPanel to hold the GUI, and then give it components and or other JPanels each using its own layout manager. Then create your JDialog or JFrame (using the API to see which constructor to use), add your main JPanel to the top level window (actually to its contentPane) by calling `add(myMainPanel)`, pack the top level window by calling `pack()`, and display it via `setVisible(true)`.

The key issue for a dialog window is often **when** to query its contents. If it's a modal dialog, then that's easy -- you query the contents (the state of its fields) after the call to display the dialog, since that code flow will resume once the dialog is no longer visible. For a non-modal dialog, then you'd need to add a WindowListener to notify you when the dialog is no longer visible.

For more specific help, you need to ask a more specific question and show code.